# Why cannot write log to files when WPF application publishing as a single file

Tags: wpf, .net-core, nlog

I use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` and `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` in WPF. The application run correctly with `Debug`  and `Release` mode, But when I publish the app as a single file, I found `File` target does not work when `fileName` using relative path.

**NLog version**: 4.6.8
**Platform**:  .NET Core 3
NLog config

```xml
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <default-wrapper xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="100"/>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="logs/${level}-${shortdate}.log" encoding="utf-8"
            layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" final="true"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I use `AddNLog` to apply this configuration:

```cs
public App()
{
    _host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureLogging(logBuilder =>
        {
            logBuilder.ClearProviders()
            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
            .AddNLog("NLog.config");
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            //...
        }).Build();
}
```

Show the MainWindow when application startup:

```cs
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    using var serviceScope = _host.Services.CreateScope();
    var serviceProvider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
    _logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<App>>();
    SetupExceptionHandling();
    MainWindow mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.Show();
    _logger.LogInformation($"Application startup at {DateTime.Now} successfully");
}
```

Publishing as a single file and run it, the log of successful startup is not written to the file, But when i change `fileName` to an absolute path like `/logs/${level}-${shortdate}.log` or `${level}-${shortdate}.log`, the log can be written.

I try to configure it in code:

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
var file = new FileTarget("file")
{
    FileName = "logs/${shortdate}-${level}.log",
    Layout = "${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
};
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, new BufferingTargetWrapper(file));
return config;
```

But the result is still the same.

Am I writing something wrong? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog will automatically prefix relative fileName-path with the `${basedir}`-layout. See also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Basedir-Layout-Renderer

Sadly enough Microsoft decided not to fix `AppDomain.BaseDirectory` when doing Single File Publish in NetCore 3.1

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12621
- https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/7491

The work-around is to explictly specify `${basedir:fixTempDir=true}`:

```xml
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <default-wrapper xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="100"/>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="${basedir:fixtempdir=true}/logs/${level}-${shortdate}.log" encoding="utf-8"
            layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" final="true"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Hopefully Microsoft will fix the illusion with NetCore5

Comment: I did not find the relevant issue in the nlog repository before, but I found this [issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3808) from the link you gave.`${basedir:fixTempDir=true}` is useful, thank you very much!